# Need help displaying min/max values of integers entered by user

Tags: c++

I need help with a c++ program that:

"Prompts  users  for  N  integers  and  determines/displays  the  integer 
with  the  highest  and  lowest  value  –  use  separate  functions  to  return  the  highest  and lowest value.  N is a random number from 5 to 10 (both inclusive)."

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void randNumGenerator();
void smallestNum(int);
void largestNum(int);

int smallNum;
int largeNum;
int randomNum;
int num[10];

int main()
{
    smallestNum(smallNum);
    largestNum(largeNum);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void randNumGenerator()
{
    srand(time(0));
    randomNum = 5 + (rand() % 10);

    for (int x = 1; x <= randomNum; x++) {
        cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        cin >> num[randomNum];
    }
}

void smallestNum(int smallNum)
{
    randNumGenerator();

    smallNum = num[randomNum];
    for (int i = 0; randomNum <= i; i++)
        if (num[randomNum] < smallNum)
        {
            smallNum = num[randomNum];
        }
    cout << "The smallest integer is: " << smallNum << endl;
}

void largestNum(int largeNum)
{
    randNumGenerator();

    largeNum = num[randomNum];
    for (int i = 0; i <= i; i++)
        if (num[randomNum] > largeNum)
        {
            largeNum = num[randomNum];
        }
    cout << "The largest integer is: " << largeNum << endl;
}
```

But, my code is not working and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "my code is not working" ?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= i; i++) => you made an error in the condition

Comment: When I run the code it doesn't return the correct minimum number and then it asks the user for another set of numbers without even giving the maximum number.

Comment: `randomNum = 5 + (rand() % 10);` -- This value will exceed the bounds of the `num` array if `rand() % 10` is greater than 4.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, how would I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void randNumGenerator();
void smallestNum();
void largestNum();
void getInput();

int num[11];
int length;

int main(){
  smallestNum();
  largestNum();
  return 0;
}

void randNumGenerator(){
  int from = 5;
  int to = 10;
  srand(time(0));
  length = from + (rand() % (to - from));
}

void getInput(){
  for (int x = 1; x <= length; x++) {
    cout << "Enter the integer num[" << x << "]: ";
    cin >> num[x];
  }
}

void smallestNum(){
  cout << "Finding smallest integer\n";
  randNumGenerator();
  getInput();
  int smallNum = num[1];
  for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    if (num[i] < smallNum)
      smallNum = num[i];
  cout << "The smallest integer is: " << smallNum << endl;
}

void largestNum(){
  cout << "Finding largest integer\n";
  randNumGenerator();
  getInput();
  int largeNum = num[1];
  for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    if (num[i] > largeNum)
      largeNum = num[i];
  cout << "The largest integer is: " << largeNum << endl;
}
```

With above code, I hope you will find your mistakes on your own :)

Comment: Ideally code supports an answer, rather than *being* the answer.

Comment: Ok, I understood.
It won't happen again.
Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

First, with `randomNum = 5 + (rand() % 10);`, you generate random numbers between `5` and `14`, inclusive, which may exceed `int num[10]`. Use `randomNum = 5 + (rand() % 6);` to get values between `5..10`.

In your loops `for (int i = 0; randomNum <= i; i++)`, with `random <= i`, you exceed array bounds since `randomNum` can go up to `10` and `num[10]` is already out of bounds for `int num[10]`. Write `... randomNum < i` instead.

The same problem with `smallNum = num[randomNum]`; it exceeds array bounds; use `smallNum = num[0]` instead.

BTW: I'd interpret your assignment such that you enter the numbers once and then find the smallest and largest number in two different functions. In your code, you enter the numbers twice...

And: It's useless passing the `smallNum` into the function that overrides its value then. I'd rather use a function like `int smallestNum() { ... return smallNum; }` instead.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, this loop makes no sense:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= randomNum; x++) {
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> num[randomNum];
}
```

`randomNum` is the same every loop, so you just keep overwriting the same array value.

And...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= i; i++)
```

This loop is wrong. You are checking `i <= i` which will always evaluate true.